# Accessing a return object/value from Electron ipcRenderer.invoke()

Tags: javascript, electron

With 'response_' declared globally, calling the simple function

```
    function getResponse() {
        ipcRenderer.invoke('responseChan').then((result) => {
            response_ = result
            console.log('getResponse invocation returned: ',response_)
        })
        return response_
    }
```

behaves as expected, asynchronously providing the expected function return value / object when the promise is resolved.

But how is the .invoke method used to await the response value / object in such 'getResponse' function? I have difficulty accessing that, when coded as follows:

```
    async function getResponse() {
        response_ = await ipcRenderer.invoke('responseChan')
        return response_
    }
```

As expected for this async function, the renderer console logs:

```
    getResponse returned:  Promise {<pending>}__proto__: Promise
    [[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
    [[PromiseValue]]: "On",
```

but what method is required to access the resolved PromiseValue (in this case, "On")?

main code is:

```
ipcMain.handle('responseChan', (respAwaited) => {
   response = visca_decode()
   console.log('visca_decode response: ', response)   
   mainWindow.webContents.send('camRespChan', response)
   let resp = (response === 'Stby') ? 'Camera 1 on Standby' : 'Camera 1 Powered and Selected'
   mainWindow.webContents.send('displayChan', resp)   
   //mainWindow.webContents.send('displayChan', 'Command acknowledged')
   return response
})
```

Comment: i'm not really understanding the question. are you saying that response_ gets set to a promsie instead of the actual result? You'd need to show us what your ipcMain.handle("responseChan") code looks like

Comment: Yes; getResponse using '.then' method provides the result "On" asynchronously (when promise is resolved). I understand async getResponse .. await should not return until the promise is resolved, but the result is not meaningful to the coded calling that function.

Comment: Main handler code is unchanged for both test cases:

Comment: Without 'await' in the call to ipcRenderer.invoke, it is expected that getResponse initially returns only a promise - but including 'await' evidently does not alter behaviour, to suspend execution until the promise is resolved. Perhaps I misunderstand the function of 'await'.

Comment: Misunderstanding of async .. await usage led to the particular phrasing of this question, which should perhaps be worded 'how can one test if a promise has been resolved?' A global semaphore may be applied, to be set when function execution resumes following 'await' - and tested to determine promise resolution. Is there a more direct means of determining state of a promise, in order to avoid potential code race bugs?

Comment: The race condition which led to the original question is avoided by moving the dependent code fragment into getResponse, as shown below. This change may give rise to a different race condition, resolvable by semaphore use, unless a direct test of promise state is available in Electron.

Answer (score 1):

Misunderstanding of async .. await usage led to the particular phrasing of the question, which should perhaps be worded 'how to test if a promise has been resolved'.

Use of a semaphore is apparent, set when function execution resumes following 'await' - and tested to determine resolution, unless there a more direct means of determining promise state, in order to avoid potential code race bugs.

The race condition which led to the original question is avoided by moving the dependent code fragment into getResponse, as shown below. This change may give rise to a different race condition, resolvable by semaphore use unless a direct test of promise state exists.

```
  async function getResponse() {
  response_ = 'Response_ pending'
  console.log('response_ initialisation: ', response_)
  response_ = await ipcRenderer.invoke('responseChan')  //After calling .invoke,
              //getResponse returns with response_ set to the unresolved promise
  console.log('"Awaited" response_: ', response_)     //Succeeding code executes
  //return response_                //asynchronously, on resolution of the promise
  switch (response_) {              //This switch statement, which failed on
    case 'Stby':                    //unresolved promise when coded in line with
      args = [0, 'CAM_Power', 'On'] //call to getResponse, works here, since it
      response = executeCommand(args) //executes only when the promise is resolved!
      console.log('Switch stmt recognized: Camera 1 powered and selected')
      break;
```

...